# How to add AutoCompleteBox into Datagrid column?

Tags: xaml, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

How to add `AutoCompleteBox()` into a `Datagrid` Column ?

Answer (score 1):

You would normally use a DataTemplateColumn to template the layout.